# Batch file for calling systeminfo on multiple machines

Tags: batch-file

So, due to a recent change in structuring at the company I work for, we have gotten behind by a lot on our PC Inventory.  I know how to run and export the file as CSV on every computer individually but of course that is time consuming.  What I am looking for is this:

I need to place the machine names or IPs into a text file (pclist.txt)
I need to create a batch file to run only on the specified PCs in pclist.txt
Finally I need the info dumped to a file

The code I use on single machines is:

```
`systeminfo /s 'pcnameoriphere' /fo CSV >\Desktop\CurrentPC.csv`
```

How would I make that single machine code work on multiple machines?  I know there is a way to do it but for the life of me I cannot remember it and none of the things I've read quite do what I need.  Any help is fantastic.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a cmd prompt, do

```js
md "%userprofile%\Desktop\Inventory"
for /f "usebackq delims=" %I in ("pclist.txt") do systeminfo /s %I /fo csv >"%userprofile%\desktop\inventory\%I.csv"`
```

From a batch script, double-up on the `%%` signs in `%%I`.  It might be possible to get the results more quickly by running `systeminfo` asynchronously, but I think you might have to call a batch script on each iteration like this:

batch script:

```js
@echo off
setlocal

md "%userprofile%\Desktop\Inventory" >NUL 2>NUL
systeminfo /s %~1 /fo csv >"%userprofile%\desktop\inventory\%~1.csv"
```

cmd prompt:

```js
for /f "usebackq delims=" %I in ("pclist.txt") do start /b batfile.bat %I
```

It gets confusing trying to redirect the output of a command launched by `start /b`.  Does the `>` apply to `start /b` itself, or to the command run by `start /b`?  Should the `>` be escaped?

It's just easier to follow the logic by putting the redirection within a script.  Then there's no ambiguity between what you intend and what cmd thinks you intend.

Comment: That seems to be almost precisely what I need.  Let me run a few tests and I will let you know.  Thanks!